# org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 681

Tags: spring, hibernate

> ```
> Dec 17, 2015 3:49:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/crafartweb] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
> ```
>
> exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with
>   the given identifier was found: 681, for class:
>   com.crafart.dataobjects.StoreDO] with root cause
>       org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 681, for class: com.crafart.dataobjects.StoreDO
>         at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:104)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:161)
>         at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2374)
>         at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:722)
>         at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:492)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1112)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:969)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2548)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2534)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2364)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2359)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1194)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
>         at com.crafart.data.SellerDAOImpl.getSellerDetails(SellerDAOImpl.java:82)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getSellerDetails(Unknown Source)
>         at com.crafart.seller.service.ManageSellerServiceImpl.getSellerDetails(ManageSellerServiceImpl.java:170)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getSellerDetails(Unknown Source)
>         at com.crafart.MenuController.showManageSellers(MenuController.java:216)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run
>       (Thread.java:744)

```
My StoreClass is ---
/**
 * 
 */
package com.crafart.dataobjects;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * store entity data object maps to store table in crafart database. Property
 * belongs to store table and store_id is primary key which is generated by db
 * sequence <blockquote>seq_store<blockquote>
 * 
 * @author Karthi
 * @version 1.0
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORE")
public class StoreDO implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3168290124126749175L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "store_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_store", sequenceName = "seq_store", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_store")
    private long storeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id", nullable = false)
    private SellerDO sellerDO;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "store_url")
    private String storeUrl;

    @Column(name = "store_description")
    private String storeDescription;

    @Column(name = "return")
    private String storeReturn;

    public SellerDO getSellerDO() {
        return sellerDO;
    }

    public void setSellerDO(SellerDO sellerDO) {
        this.sellerDO = sellerDO;
    }

    public long getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(long storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStoreUrl() {
        return storeUrl;
    }

    public void setStoreUrl(String storeUrl) {
        this.storeUrl = storeUrl;
    }

    public String getStoreDescription() {
        return storeDescription;
    }

    public void setStoreDescription(String store_Description) {
        this.storeDescription = store_Description;
    }

    public String getStoreReturn() {
        return storeReturn;
    }

    public void setStoreReturn(String store_Return) {
        this.storeReturn = store_Return;
    }
}

**
```

> `storeBO class is this`

**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.crafart.dataobjects;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * seller entity data object maps to seller table in crafart database. Property
 * belongs to seller table and seller_id is primary key which is generated by db
 * sequence <blockquote>seq_seller<blockquote>
 * 
 * @author karthi
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "SELLER")
public class SellerDO implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    /**
     * generated serial id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2950842206999695829L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seller_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_seller", sequenceName = "seq_seller", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_seller")
    private long sellerId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sellerDO", targetEntity=StoreDO.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private StoreDO storeDO;

    @Column(name = "first_Name")
    private String firstName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "SELLER_ADDRESS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SELLER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID") })
    private List<AddressDO> addressDOs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "SELLER_CONTACT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SELLER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID") })
    private List<ContactDO> contactDOs = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sellerDOs")
    private List<ProductDO> productDOs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "last_Name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private int gender;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    private int tin_no;

    @Column(name = "company_Name")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "company_Logo")
    private String companyLogo;

    @Column(name = "epch_no")
    private String epchNo;

    @Column(name = "vat_no")
    private String vat_no;

    @Column(name = "cst_no")
    private String cst_no;

    /*
     * add variables
     *  */

    @Column(name = "gst_no")
    private String gst_no;

    @Column(name = "officeno")
    private int officeno;

    @Column(name = "mobileno")
    private int mobileno;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "panno")
    private String panno;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "commission_id",nullable = true)
    private CommissionDO commissionDO;

    private int status;

    private int approved;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "confirm_password")
    private String confirmpassword;

    public String getEpchNo() {
        return epchNo;
    }

    public void setEpchNo(String epchNo) {
        this.epchNo = epchNo;
    }

    public String getConfirmpassword() {
        return confirmpassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmpassword(String confirmpassword) {
        this.confirmpassword = confirmpassword;
    }

    public long getSellerId() {
        return sellerId;
    }

    public void setSellerId(long sellerId) {
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getTin_no() {
        return tin_no;
    }

    public void setTin_no(int tin_no) {
        this.tin_no = tin_no;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCompanyLogo() {
        return companyLogo;
    }

    public void setCompanyLogo(String companyLogo) {
        this.companyLogo = companyLogo;
    }

    public String getEpch_no() {
        return epchNo;
    }

    public void setEpch_no(String epch_no) {
        this.epchNo = epch_no;
    }

    public String getVat_no() {
        return vat_no;
    }

    public int getOfficeno() {
        return officeno;
    }

    public void setOfficeno(int officeno) {
        this.officeno = officeno;
    }

    public int getMobileno() {
        return mobileno;
    }

    public void setMobileno(int mobileno) {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPanno() {
        return panno;
    }

    public void setPanno(String panno) {
        this.panno = panno;
    }

    public void setVat_no(String vat_no) {
        this.vat_no = vat_no;
    }

    public String getCst_no() {
        return cst_no;
    }

    public void setCst_no(String cst_no) {
        this.cst_no = cst_no;
    }
    public String getGst_no() {
        return gst_no;
    }

    public void setGst_no(String gst_no) {
        this.gst_no = gst_no;
    }

    public CommissionDO getCommissionDO() {
        return commissionDO;
    }

    public void setCommissionDO(CommissionDO commissionDO) {
        this.commissionDO = commissionDO;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(int approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public int getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(int gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public List<ContactDO> getContactDOs() {
        return contactDOs;
    }

    public void setContactDOs(List<ContactDO> contactDOs) {
        this.contactDOs = contactDOs;
    }

    public StoreDO getStoreDO() {
        return storeDO;
    }

    public void setStoreDO(StoreDO storeDO) {
        this.storeDO = storeDO;

    }

    public List<AddressDO> getAddressDOs() {
        return addressDOs;
    }

    public void setAddressDOs(List<AddressDO> addressDOs) {
        this.addressDOs = addressDOs;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<ProductDO> getProductDOs() {
        return productDOs;
    }

    public void setProductDOs(List<ProductDO> productDOs) {
        this.productDOs = productDOs;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid mapping

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sellerDO", targetEntity=StoreDO.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private StoreDO storeDO;
```

Should be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sellerDO", targetEntity=StoreDO.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<StoreDO> storeDO;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sellerDO", targetEntity=StoreDO.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<StoreDO> storeDO;
```